# PHPDoc - Reference to equal comments

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I want to know if it is possible to refer from a parameter of a method to a property of the same class to share the same comment. I'm going to explain:

I have this property:

```
/**
 * This makes something very cool.
 */
 private $foo;
```

And this method whose parameter refers to the previous property.

```
/**
 * Setter foo.
 * @param string $foo This makes something very cool.
 */
 public function setFoo($foo)
 {
     $this->foo = $foo;
 }
```

I do not want to write twice the same comment, is there any way that the parameter has commented the comment of the property ?, something like this:

```
/**
 * This makes something very cool.
 */
 private $foo;

/**
 * Setter foo.
 * @param string $foo [Reference to $foo comment]
 */
 public function setFoo($foo)
 {
     $this->foo = $foo;
 }
```

Thanks, greetings.

Comment: Maybe `@see` tag? Or `@uses`?

Comment: Thanks for answering @u_mulder but I do not need to add an external reference or detail, I would like appear the comment nexto to param that I have stated elsewhere. I think I have not been able to explain very well, I think those two options do not serve me or I've tried. But thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that. Technically you want to keep the two separated anyway, as `setFoo` is the public interface but the property `$foo` is internal implementation. Outside users shouldn't know or assume that `setFoo` automatically uses a property `$foo`.